# Adding own points to PostGIS database

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, nominatim

I have imported some data from OSM. And it's okay. But for my own purposes I want to add mine addresses using Postgis.

I googled this for a few days and the only idea I came invented is to prepare OSM XML, then convert this using available tools, finally - import to PostGIS

But how to achieve this using the shortest path?

Comment: If it's point data, the quickest way is probably to write an insert query. But it depends on how many records, format etc. So... can you share some data and tell us what format your own data is in?

Comment: Just want to append a simple address having lat and long.

Comment: This would work, so long as your srid matches: insert into table (geometry) select ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lon, lat),4326)

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite new to the PostGIS, which table should I use and how attach address tags data?

Comment: Don't know what tables you have! Actually, I'd be tempted to create a new table and store your own data in there. You can always merge the data afterwards if you need to.

Comment: I've written (especially within tags) what I'm using. Pure Nominatim, don't think that there's anything unknown.

Comment: Added data to the table but nominatim cannot fetch data from this table...